# Plotting multidimensional tables

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

I have a tridiagonal matrix created by

```
Amat[x_, y_, a_, n_] := SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> x}, {n, n}] 
                       +SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> y}, {n, n}] 
                       +SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> a}, {n, n}];
```

Here `x,y,a` are real numbers and `n` is an integer.
To plot eigenvalues of this matrix at `n=2`, I use

```
r1 = Table[{x, Sort[Re[Eigenvalues[Amat[x, 1.2, 0.3, 2]]]][[1]]}, {x, -4, 
2, 6/10}];
r2 = Table[{x, Sort[Re[Eigenvalues[Amat[x, 1.2, 0.3, 2]]]][[2]]}, {x, -4, 
2, 6/10}];

g1 = ListLinePlot[r1,PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick, Opacity[0.95]], Mesh -> False];
g2 = ListLinePlot[r2,PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick, Opacity[0.95]], Mesh -> False];

Show[g1, g2, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

The problem with this way of plotting is that I have to modify my script for each `n` value to collect other eigenvalues, similar to `(r1,r2)` and `(g1,g2)`. Do you have a suggestion on improving this script so that I can plot all eigenvalues with a given symbolic variable `n`?
For example, when `n=5`, the matrix has five eigenvalues. I would like to have a script that generates a single plot with all five eigenvalues in this case.

Also, is there a way to plot all eigenvalues in`rn`, given by

```
 rn = Table[{x, Sort[Re[Eigenvalues[Amat[x, 1.2, 0.3, n]]]]}, {x, -4, 2, 6/10}];
```

as a function of `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution after discussion with the author of the OP**

```
Amat[x_, y_, a_, n_] := 
  SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> x}, {n, n}] + 
   SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> y}, {n, n}] + 
   SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> a}, {n, n}];
r[n_, part_] := 
 Table[{x, 
   Sort[Re[Eigenvalues[Amat[x, 1.2, 0.3, n]]]][[part]]}, {x, -4, 2, 
   6/10}]
g[n_, part_] := 
 ListLinePlot[r[n, part], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick, Opacity[0.95]], Mesh -> False]
show[n_] := 
 Show[Table[g[n, ii], {ii, 1, n}], AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

Reproducing the result of the OP:

```
show[2]
```

> [image: opres]

Higher-order values for $n$

```
Grid[{Table[show[xx], {xx, 2, 7}]}]
```

> [image: graphs1]

and even higher values

```
Partition[Table[show[xx], {xx, 2, 21}], 3]
```

> [image: bigone]

---

**Checking the validity of the suggested solution.**

Here we follow the steps of the author of the OP and create the cases `n=3` and `n=4` manually to check the answer. The `n=2` case is explicitly presented in the OP.

- `n=3`

We have

```
r1 = Table[{x, 
    Sort[Re[Eigenvalues[Amat[x, 1.2, 0.3, 3]]]][[1]]}, {x, -4, 2, 
    6/10}];
r2 = Table[{x, 
    Sort[Re[Eigenvalues[Amat[x, 1.2, 0.3, 3]]]][[2]]}, {x, -4, 2, 
    6/10}];
r3 = Table[{x, 
    Sort[Re[Eigenvalues[Amat[x, 1.2, 0.3, 3]]]][[3]]}, {x, -4, 2, 
    6/10}];
g1 = ListLinePlot[r1, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick, Opacity[0.95]], 
   Mesh -> False];
g2 = ListLinePlot[r2, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick, Opacity[0.95]], 
   Mesh -> False];
g3 = ListLinePlot[r3, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick, Opacity[0.95]], 
   Mesh -> False];
Show[g1, g2, g3, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: n3manual]

- `n=4`

We have

```
r1 = Table[{x, 
    Sort[Re[Eigenvalues[Amat[x, 1.2, 0.3, 4]]]][[1]]}, {x, -4, 2, 
    6/10}];
r2 = Table[{x, 
    Sort[Re[Eigenvalues[Amat[x, 1.2, 0.3, 4]]]][[2]]}, {x, -4, 2, 
    6/10}];
r3 = Table[{x, 
    Sort[Re[Eigenvalues[Amat[x, 1.2, 0.3, 4]]]][[3]]}, {x, -4, 2, 
    6/10}];
r4 = Table[{x, 
    Sort[Re[Eigenvalues[Amat[x, 1.2, 0.3, 4]]]][[4]]}, {x, -4, 2, 
    6/10}];
g1 = ListLinePlot[r1, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick, Opacity[0.95]], 
   Mesh -> False];
g2 = ListLinePlot[r2, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick, Opacity[0.95]], 
   Mesh -> False];
g3 = ListLinePlot[r3, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick, Opacity[0.95]], 
   Mesh -> False];
g4 = ListLinePlot[r4, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick, Opacity[0.95]], 
   Mesh -> False];
Show[g1, g2, g3, g4, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: n4manual]

Comment: Thanks! Could you provide an explanation for your script? Could you also plot all Eigenvalues for a fixed ```n```, say ```n=5```,  in one plot instead of multiple panels?

Comment: @Shasa I am not sure what is not clear, so it would be very helpful if you could explain what comments you'd like to see. Essentially, I just read the code you provided, tested it and used functions so I can change automatically the values of `n` and the [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) command. This is why `show[2]` reproduces both of the plots you needed to manually generate. Likewise for higher `n` values. The `n=5` is the last value of the [`GraphicsGrid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsGrid.html). Have I misunderstood what you asked?

Comment: When ```n=3```, the matrix has three eigenvalues. I would like to have a plot with three eigenvalues in this case. Similarly, for larger values, e.g., ```n=5```, I would like to have a single plot with all five eigenvalues. As in```show``` two ```g``` are manually inserted, then I can't get all eigenvalues in one plot, right?

Comment: @Shasa oh I see. I misunderstood what you wrote in the OP. I am sorry. Let me think a bit about that and I will revisit. In the meantime, I will delete this answer so others can notice. Just let me know when you see this message so I can delete

Comment: Thank you for revisiting your answer.

Comment: @Shasa can you have a look now? I did the value `n=3` using the logic of your code and then I automated the solution for general `n`. Please let me know if you agree and like the solution :)

Comment: The updated answer is very good. Thanks!

Comment: @Shasa glad I was able to help :-)